# Using properties to transfer data between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I am trying to use properties to transfer two collections from one to another form.
However for some reason I can't see the properties from form2 in form1. The error message I get is

> System.Windows.Forms.Form does not contain a defintion for _col1 and
>   no extension method _col1 accepting a first argument of type
>   System.windows.Forms.Form....

Here is the code from Form1

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {

    private Collection<string> col1;
    private Collection<string> col2;

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form frm1 = new Form2();

        //fill collections with some kind of data

        frm1._col1 = _col1;
        frm1._col2 = _col2;

        frm1.Show();
    }
    public Collection<string> _col2
    {
        get { return col2; }
    }

    public Collection<string> _col1
    {
        get { return col1; }
    }
 }
```

Here is the code from Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Collection<string> col1;
    private Collection<string> col2;        

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Collection<string> _col1
    {
        get { return col1; }

        set { col1 = value; }
    }

    public Collection<string> _col2
    {
        get { return col2; }

        set { col2 = value; }
    }
}
```

According to the articles I have read everything should work - however I am not able to access the Form2 properties from Form1.

What am I missing??

Comment: Although you are instantiating Form2, your local reference is to the base `Form`. Change the line in `btn1_Click` to `Form2 frm1 = new Form2();` (and think of giving your class and local variables more meaningful names)

Comment: not that it would make a difference, but normally private members are the ones that start with an underscore

Comment: Thanks StuartLC - that was the solution.

Comment: Thanks CoderDennis for the advice - I'll change the names to match common standards.  I am pretty new to programming and still have a lot to learn...

Comment: @Stefan: If your issue is solved, please mark one of the answers that explain how to solve the problem as accepted. This will signal future visitors that the question is answered, and in which answer to find a working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared your `frm1` variable like this:

```
Form frm1 = new Form2();
```

Therefore, the compiler will assume it is of type [`Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). As the error message correctly explains, `Form` does not have any property or method named `_col1`.

If you declare your variable as belonging to type `Form2` instead, the compiler will find your properties:

```
Form2 frm1 = new Form2();
```

As commented by [CoderDennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69527/coderdennis), you can also use the [`var` keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383973%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) instead of explicitly declaring the type for the variable:

```
var frm1 = new Form2();
```

Be aware, though, that the [C# programming guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384061.aspx) cautions:

> However, the use of var does have at least the potential to make your code more difficult to understand for other developers. For that reason, the C# documentation generally uses var only when it is required.

Which is not an unwise idea for code in general, as long as `var` doesn't replace something really cumbersome to write (e.g. generic types).

---

*A remark on coding style: Convention has it that properties start with capital letters, so you may want to rename your properties from `_col1` and `_col2` to `Col1` and `Col2`, respectively.*

*If you then want to clearly visually distinguish the properties from the private backing fields, put the underscore in the name of the private fields, as correctly pointed out by [CoderDennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69527/coderdennis) in his comment.*

Comment: Or use `var frm1`, which will do the same thing as `Form2 frm1` without having to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Update the reference as following:

```
Form2 frm1 = new Form2();
```

col1 is declated in Form2 class.
Since Form1 and Form2 classes have the same properties you can consider creating an

```
interface IFormWithCollection
{
Collection<string> _col1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    Collection<string> _col2
    {
        get;  set;
    }
}
```

And then implement the Fom1 and Form2 definitions: `Form1 : Form, IFormWithCollection`

```
Form2 : Form, IFormWithCollection
```

And then:

```
IFormWithCollection frm1 = new Form2();
```

Comment: Using the interface is only adviseable if instances of the two classes are meant to be interchangeable in any situation.